# Algorithm for matching arrays of integers (fingerprints)

Tags: algorithm

I'm looking for an algorithm for matching two arrays of integers. For example:

Reference:

```
00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0A 0B 0C 0D 0E 0F
```

Candidate:

```
FF FF FF 01 02 03 FF AA 09 0A 0B 0C 0D 0E FF
```

Desired output:

```
01 02 03 09 0A 0B 0C 0D 0E
```

// Clarification
I'm interested in finding consecutive matches. In real world example there will be lots of singular matches (noise) and perhaps 1 to 3 bigger clusters.

Reference and Candidate are approximations (fingerprints) of text (like book). Small range matches are meaningless. Values inside fingerprint are hashes of K-Grams so values are not unique.

Comment: are both sequence of integers always sorted or in increasing/decreasing order?

Comment: Oh sorry, this example might be confusing. Sequences are never sorted.

Comment: This is essentially what diff does (just replace lines by your 8-bit tokens) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diff_utility There are lot of heuristics to handle the *well behaved* cases.

Comment: When you say *sequences are never sorted*, that leaves it unclear as to whether you want a longest common subsequence, or whether you just want to find which elements are common to both arrays, regardless of order. @MAK has answered according to the first interpretation; I've answered according to the second. But it would be as well to clarify (by editing the question, rather than in a comment).

Comment: You need to define the rules for minimum sequence lengths that constitute a match. If you did not care about consecutivity then it could be done very quickly by putting one of them into a hashtable then looking through the other for comparisons. The same could possibly be done using a hashtable of key->position. I've actually done a fingerprinting algorithm for fuzzy matching of books before, are you comparing 1 to 1, or 1 to many?

Comment: once candidate to many references (and by many I mean hundreds of thousands)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like what you need is the [Longest Common Subsequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem) of two lists.

Answer (score 1):

Simply you can start with one of them. pop a value, compare it to the other array values one by one, till the end of it. and pop another value to check, and so on...!

Answer (score 1):

> NOTE: you've said in a comment that *arrays are never sorted*. I'm taking this to mean that you're not looking for the longest common subsequence, but just wanting to identify which elements in the candidate array are also present in the reference array, *regardless of order* (i.e., a set intersection). If this is not right, please clarify the question!

You can do this in O(n+m) time, where n and m are the lengths of the lists. This is much faster than the naive approach of going through the first list and checking, for each element, whether it's contained in the second list.

I am assuming, from your example, that your reference array doesn't contain duplicates. There are ways of dealing with this if it does, but it's then not entirely clear what you want your output to look like.

The posh way to do it is to construct a *bit field*, which is a data structure that tells you whether any given element is present or absent, and it represents each possible element with a single bit. You can thus use a single `int` to represent 32 different in/out values. There's an [Apache Commons](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.3.2/org/apache/commons/lang3/BitField.html) implementation available that you can use straight off.

The way to solve your problem is then to go through your reference array, putting each element of it into the bit field. Once you've done this, you effectively have a `Set`, and you can test, for any given value, whether it was in your reference array by looking to see whether its bit is set in the bit field. So now you go through your candidate array, and for each element, you test for its presence in the bit field.

Even if the range of possible values is huge, you can still do it this way. Even if all possible `int` values are allowed, you can still represent all of them in 1GB of memory.

It looks from your example as though the number of possible values is small, in which case you can do it more simply, and also handle duplicates, just by having an `int[]` array, one for each possible value. So if the range of values is 0 to 999, then you declare

```
int[] present = new int[1000];
```

and then you go through your reference array:

```
for (int ref: refArray)
    present[ref]++;
```

Now you have a count of the number of occurrences of each value in your `present` array. You go through your candidate array, and look up, for each one, how many times it's in the `present` array:

```
for (int cand: candidateArray)
    if (present[cand]>0)
        System.out.println(cand+" occurred "+present[cand]+" times in the ref array");
```

If you won't get duplicates in the reference array, you could just use a `boolean[]`, of course.

This is **much** faster than the other suggested ways of doing it, which are O(n*m).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. You shared some useful ideas which are helpful but I worry my question is still confusing. I do apologise for that. Values are not unique. I'm interested in the biggest ranges of consecutive matches.

Answer (score 0):

since both sequences are not sorted you have to check each vaue individually. This java code will give your desired output:

```
for(int i=0;i<array2.length();i++)
{
    for(int j=0;j<array1.length();j++)
    {
       if(array1[j].equals(array2[i])
       {
           System.out.println(array2[i]+" ");
       }
    }
}
```